# DropDown Menu won't show for more than a second..not working.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Trying to make my own responsive mobile drop-down menu with its corresponding sub-menus.

So far I have the basic layout.
The user should be able to toggle between showing those sub-menus.
When "WORK" is clicked no other sub-menu should be open.
I've gone ahead and added the "display: none;" property to hide the sub-menus.
Trying to use jQuery to show() and hide() them when they are clicked.
I've looked around and test various methods. So far none worked.
The code is as follows

**HTML**

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul class="topLinksUL">
        <li class="topLinksLI"><a class="topLinksA" title="Home" id="home" href="">HOME</a>
            <ul class="abtDropUL">
                <li class="abtDropLI"><a class="dropLinksA" href=""></a></li>
            </ul>                           
        </li>
        <li class="topLinksLI"><a class="topLinksA" title="Work" id="wrk" href="">WORK</a> 
            <ul class="workDropUL">
                <li class="workDropLI"><a class="dropLinksA" href="">Projects</a></li>
                <li class="workDropLI"><a class="dropLinksA" href="">Education</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="topLinksLI"><a class="topLinksA" title="About Me" id="abt" href="">ABOUT ME</a> 
            <ul class="abtDropUL">
                <li class="abtDropLI"><a class="dropLinksA" href="">Bio</a></li>
                <li class="abtDropLI"><a class="dropLinksA" href="">Interests</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="topLinksLI"><a class="topLinksA" title="Contact Me" id="contact" href="">CONTACT&nbsp;ME</a>
            <ul class="contactDropUL">
                <li class="contactDropLI"><a class="dropLinksA" href="">Email</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav><!-- ends nav -->
```

**CSS**

```
nav{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Centering the LIST ITEMS within the UL List ITems*/
nav ul li ul.workDropUL, nav ul li ul.abtDropUL, nav ul li ul.contactDropUL{
    padding-left: 0;
    display: none;

}
ul{
    margin: 0.2em 0;
}

body{
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif; 
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#wrk').click(function() {
    $(".workDropUL").show();

});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEOJQQ  - provided the link so you can test it out.

**Methods tried**

[How do I hide the ul's that are not clicked and show submenu in Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350181/how-do-i-hide-the-uls-that-are-not-clicked-and-show-submenu-in-jquery)

[How to fix this JQuery dropdown menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707865/how-to-fix-this-jquery-dropdown-menu?rq=1)

**MAIN POINT**
Some of these fixes do **WORK** but they only show the sub-menu for a second.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for "preventDefault".  Try something like this for your JS:

```
$('#wrk').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $(".workDropUL").show();
});
```

Edit: Here's the article about preventDefault() on the jQuery API site: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: It turned out I was importing the jquery file the wrong way. Thnks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

By default when you hit a **anchor tag** it looking for navigation if the herf="" it take reload the page.so you can handel the herf="#"([demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emNGpG)) or use span tag ([demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYGXGJ))

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul class="topLinksUL">
        <li class="topLinksLI"><a class="topLinksA" title="Home" id="home" href="">HOME</a>
            <ul class="abtDropUL">
                <li class="abtDropLI"><a class="dropLinksA" href=""></a></li>
            </ul>                           
        </li>
        <li class="topLinksLI"><span class="topLinksA" title="Work" id="wrk" href="">WORK</span> 
            <ul class="workDropUL">
                <li class="workDropLI"><a class="dropLinksA" href="">Projects</a></li>
                <li class="workDropLI"><a class="dropLinksA" href="">Education</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="topLinksLI"><a class="topLinksA" title="About Me" id="abt" href="">ABOUT ME</a>
            <ul class="abtDropUL">
                <li class="abtDropLI"><a class="dropLinksA" href="">Bio</a></li>
                <li class="abtDropLI"><a class="dropLinksA" href="">Interests</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="topLinksLI"><a class="topLinksA" title="Contact Me" id="contact" href="">CONTACT&nbsp;ME</a>
            <ul class="contactDropUL">
                <li class="contactDropLI"><a class="dropLinksA" href="">Email</a></li>
                <li class="contactDropLI"><a class="dropLinksA" href="">Facebook</a></li>
                <li class="contactDropLI"><a class="dropLinksA" href="">Instagram</a></li>
                <li class="contactDropLI"><a class="dropLinksA" href="">Linked&nbsp;In</a></li>
                <li class="contactDropLI"><a class="dropLinksA" href="">StackOverflow</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav><!-- ends nav -->



$('#wrk').click(function() {
    $(".workDropUL").toggle();

});
```

Comment: It turned out I was importing the jquery file the wrong way. Thnks for your help.